# Visualising GLMM using pred() function

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict, glmmtmb

I applied the following GLMM to my data using `glmmTMB`.

```
M1 <- glmmTMB(Count1 ~ Count2 + Year + Location + Depth + 
             (1|Site/Transect), 
             data = df, 
             family = "nbinom2")
```

With random-effects `Site` and `Transect`. `Year`, `Location`, and `Depth` are all factors.
I want to plot `Count1` (response variable) against `Count2` (explanatory variable). So I produced a grid of covariate values for Count2.

```
MyData <- ddply(df, 
            .(fYear, fLocation, fDepth, Site, Transect), 
            summarize,
            count2 = seq(from = min(df$Count2), 
                     to = max(df$Count2), 
                     length = 25))
```

Here I sample 25 values between the min and max.

I then predicted the expected values for the response variable (abundance)

```
P1 <- predict(M1, newdata = MyData, type = "link", se = TRUE)
```

Next I calculated 95% confidence intervals for these predicted values

```
MyData$Pred <- exp(P1$fit)                    #Predicted values.
MyData$selo <- exp(P1$fit - 1.96 * P1$se.fit) #Lower bound 95%CI.
MyData$seup <- exp(P1$fit + 1.96 * P1$se.fit) #Upper bound 95%CI.
```

Before plotting the made-up covariate values versus the corresponding predicted values.

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data = df, 
                aes(y = Count1, x = Count2))
p <- p + geom_line(data = MyData, 
               aes(x = count2, y = Pred), 
               colour = "black")
p <- p + geom_ribbon(data = MyData, 
                 aes(x = Count2,
                     ymax = seup, 
                     ymin = selo),
                 alpha = 0.5) 
p <- p + facet_grid(~Location, scale = "free_x")
p
```

This, however, gives me a very strange graph - (NOTE -  "Abundance of S.adustus" is `Count1` and "Abundance of Predators > 0.75 KG" is `Count2`.)

[image: See below]

that has a smoother and CIs that repeat across the graph and appear to be split up by 'Site'

[image: See below].

I want a smoother and corresponding CIs that works at the `Location` level. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?
dput of reproducible data:

```r
structure(list(Year = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Utila", 
"Tela"), class = "factor"), Site = c("RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", 
"RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "RO", "BCW", "BCW", 
"BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", "BCW", 
"BCW", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", "CV", 
"CV", "CV", "CV", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", 
"LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", 
"LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "LH", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", 
"SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SB", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", 
"SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", 
"BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "BF", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"), Transect = c("RO_1", 
"RO_2", "RO_3", "RO_4", "RO_5", "RO_6", "RO_1", "RO_2", "RO_3", 
"RO_4", "RO_5", "RO_6", "BCW_1", "BCW_2", "BCW_3", "BCW_4", "BCW_5", 
"BCW_6", "BCW_1", "BCW_2", "BCW_3", "BCW_4", "BCW_5", "BCW_6", 
"CV_1", "CV_2", "CV_3", "CV_4", "CV_5", "CV_6", "CV_1", "CV_2", 
"CV_3", "CV_4", "CV_5", "CV_6", "LB_1", "LB_2", "LB_3", "LB_4", 
"LB_5", "LB_6", "LB_1", "LB_2", "LB_3", "LB_4", "LB_5", "LB_6", 
"LH_1", "LH_2", "LH_3", "LH_4", "LH_5", "LH_6", "LH_1", "LH_2", 
"LH_3", "LH_4", "LH_5", "LH_6", "SB_1", "SB_2", "SB_3", "SB_4", 
"SB_5", "SB_6", "SB_1", "SB_2", "SB_3", "SB_4", "SB_5", "SB_6", 
"SP_1", "SP_2", "SP_3", "SP_4", "SP_5", "SP_6", "SP_1", "SP_2", 
"SP_3", "SP_4", "SP_5", "SP_6", "BF_1", "BF_2", "BF_3", "BF_4", 
"BF_5", "BF_6", "BF_1", "BF_2", "BF_3", "BF_4", "BF_5", "BF_6", 
"CA_1", "CA_2", "CA_3", "CA_4", "CA_5", "CA_6", "CA_1", "CA_2", 
"CA_3", "CA_4", "CA_5", "CA_6"), Depth = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("5", "10", 
"15"), class = "factor"), Count1 = c(19L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 28L, 34L, 
1L, 1L, 17L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 29L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 24L, 4L, 17L, 6L, 
11L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Count2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 592:699)
```

Comment: Use `re.form = NA` in the `predict` to predict without random effects.

Comment: Isn't the problem with your first plot simply that you have multiple observations at each x value, so a vertical line is being drawn through all of them before jumping to the next x value?

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Apologies, I have cut the code down so it is just generic terms now. Should I produce an example df?

Comment: that would be great (that's what "reproducible" means ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Apologies. Have edited one in

Comment: I don't think that example data set is going to work; it works to show us *qualitatively* what's going on, but I very much doubt that fitting the actual model is going to work with that data set ...

Comment: @BenBolker Should be all sorted now - I've included a shortened simplified dput of Dataset. Thanks for bearing with me! Still learning - appreciate it.